# How do I get an extra level in the bootstrap hamburger menu

Tags: typo3, typo3-7.6.x

I am looking for an opportunity to expand the hamburger menu that is standard in the TYPO33 bootstrap template with an extra level. I have already searched the internet but did not find a solution. I use the standard TYPO3 bootstrap template.

Comment: what do you mean by lever? Do you mean the subpages that are supposed to be shown when the Burger menu is active?

Comment: The hamburgermenu goes now one level depth and i need a two level depth

Comment: You need to define the depth on your TypoScript. Can you share the navigation TypoScript code?

Comment: Yes i can change the code but the menu with bootstrap and typo3 is new for me

Comment: which version of TYPO3 you have installed?

Comment: I use 7.6.32 with the official introduction page version 2.3.0

Comment: regardless you problem, would you consider upgrading to TYPO3 9? Or at least TYPO3 8? TYPO3 7 support is dropped

Comment: As far as I know is the (responsive) bootstrap menu not capable to handle a third menu level. In this way you probably need more than just a third level of data which can be rendered with a further cascaded UL. In desktop mode it might work, in smartphone mode you will get problems.

Answer (score 1):

For a third menu you need to adjust three things:

1. Add a TypoScript line in your TS template (Module "Template"): `page.10.dataProcessing.10.levels = 3`
2. Set the path to the Fluid templates to a path under your control. The extension `bootstrap_package` is not under your control, on every update it will overwrite your changes in there! How to set the paths: https://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/extensions/bootstrap_package/Configuration/TypoScript/Index.html#page-fluidtemplate
3. Copy the partial `bootstrap_package/Resources/Private/Partials/Page/Navigation/Main.html` to your location and add the third level like the second level is built. Maybe you can find here more information: https://github.com/benjaminkott/bootstrap_package/issues/320

What you need is a little knowledge of TypoScript (where to find and change) and Fluid (How to use ViewHelpers)

Comment: You saved me time to install a new TYPO3 installation. I wasnt sure if the navigation was configured with dataProcessing or with HMENU TypoScript

Comment: It's like typo3 gets the tamplate from a other planet. What i do and after cleaning the cashe no result what so ever

Comment: What is your template location and what did you enter in TypoScript?